# Cells format to parse correct date format

Tags: excel, report

I want to view and order a .csv file with column date.

The format of column is:

```
2013-06-04 14:20:50.000
```

I have selected `"Cell format-> custom -> aaaa/mm/gg hh:mm:ss"` and this doesn't work if I don't erase ".000" from every cells.

What is the custom formula to format cells correctly?

I've tried:

`aaaa/mm/gg hh:mm:ss.000` but Excel tells me there is an error.

`aaaa/mm/gg hh:mm:ss".000"` but nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: `aaaa/mm/gg hh:mm:ss.000` Works fine for me. If you format as a number does it change to a number? You can't format *text* as a date. If your Dates are in text try enter a `1` in a random cell then copy the cell containing the 1 highlight all of your dates then paste special~~>multiply. See if that maybe helps

Comment: I produce csv file on "en-US" computer and read it in italian computer with Excel... i've to convert all rows of Date Columns...there are an automated function that doing this on excel?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your data is text but could easily be converted with Text to Columns, Delimited and Tab as delimiter.

Alternatively if importing with Get External Data, From Text, Delimited, at step 3 of 3 choose Column data format of Date and format the results to suit.